# Flags inside a React Bootstrap select option renders as [object, object]

Tags: css, reactjs, html-select, react-bootstrap

I want to display Flags icons inside a React Bootstrap selection Option. I have tried both CSS based and React based libraries to do so and in each case I get only `[object object]`

[image]

I have tried with the `https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css` CSS library

```
<Form.Control as="select">
         <option><span className="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span></option>
</Form.Control>
```

Which gives me a warning and the same [Object object]

```
Warning: Only strings and numbers are supported as <option> children.
```

I have also attempted with the React wrapper for the same library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flag-icon-css

```
<Form.Control as="select">
        <option><FlagIcon className="countryIcon" code="us" size="lg"/></option>
</Form.Control>
```

Which does not generate a warning but no results either

Does anyone know how I can get something else than string or number in the Option, or another way to include an icon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option HTML tag accepts text only, it can't accept any other HTML, it will strip it. You can check this React issue [[bug][16.5.0] option returns [object Object] instead of string](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13586) and read the comment by [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov):

> I don't think it was strictly a regression. This is kind of a thorny
>   area. It was never intentionally supported. It accidentally worked on
>   initial mount but then crashed on updates ([#13261](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13261)). Fixing the crash
>   was more important, so we fixed it to be treated as text content
>   (which it should be). Unfortunately this means putting custom
>   components in the middle is not supported. That's consistent with how
>   textarea and similar elements work.
>
> I think it's better to show invalid output and warn about something
>   that breaks on updates, than to let people use it only to discover it
>   crashes in production. But I can see arguments for why this should be
>   supported when the custom component returns a string. Unfortunately I
>   don't know how to fix it in a way that would both solve the update
>   crashes and support text-only content. I think for now it's reasonable
>   to say putting custom components into  doesn't really work
>   (and never quite worked correctly), and ask you to manually provide a
>   string to it.

Alternatively, you can use Bootstrap [Dropdowns](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) to create a dropdown button with a list of countries using the code below:

#### `App.js`:

```jsx
...
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import FlagIcon from './FlagIcon.js'

function App() {
  const [countries] = useState([
    { code: 'gr', title: 'Greece'},
    { code: 'gb', title: 'United Kingdom'},
    { code: 'us', title: 'United States'}
  ]);
  const [toggleContents, setToggleContents] = useState("Select a country");
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form>
        <Dropdown
          onSelect={eventKey => {
            const { code, title } = countries.find(({ code }) => eventKey === code);

            setSelectedCountry(eventKey);
            setToggleContents(<><FlagIcon code={code}/> {title}</>);
          }}
        >
          <Dropdown.Toggle variant="secondary" id="dropdown-flags" className="text-left" style={{ width: 300 }}>
            {toggleContents}
          </Dropdown.Toggle>

          <Dropdown.Menu>
            {countries.map(({ code, title }) => (
              <Dropdown.Item key={code} eventKey={code}><FlagIcon code={code}/> {title}</Dropdown.Item>
            ))}
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### `FlagIcon.js`:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import FlagIconFactory from 'react-flag-icon-css';

// const FlagIcon = FlagIconFactory(React);
// If you are not using css modules, write the following:
const FlagIcon = FlagIconFactory(React, { useCssModules: false })

export default FlagIcon;
```

You'll get a dropdown button like this:

[image: Bootstrap Dropdown Button Menu]

You can also check this working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-flags-dropdown-menu

Comment: I didn't try this answer yet, but clearly indicates that what I am trying to do cannot be achieved with pure React Bootstrap, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there can't be a native select element with options containing HTML and that's what bootstrap uses when you use `<Form.Control as="select">`, a native `<select>` element. I even tried pseudo classes like `:before` to apply the flags to options, but it didn't work. You can play with the button styles and have a button to look more like a select element. Let me know if you have any issues implementing something like what I proposed as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the tag

```
 <Form.Control as="select">
```

[object Object] is displayed e.g when you are concatenating a string with an object, for example:

```
console.log(""+{})
```

Comment: I edited the code to show the closure, which I am already doing. Unfortunately I am not doing anything beyond the code you can see. I must need to do something React specific.